# android ClassNotFoundException after trying to change minimum sdk

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I am really getting desperate.
I have a working app - theoretically.
Tried to change the sdk version from 8 to 13.

Now when I start the app I get a Fatal exception, or rather a ClassNotFoundException for the very first activity started:

```
       10-15 16:56:22.370: E/AndroidRuntime(862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pris/com.example.pris.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.pris.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.pris-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.pris-1, /system/lib]]
```

Apparently there seems to be some mixup with paths, but I have not the slightes idea where, or how to fix this.

Please help!

Comment: clean rebuild and restart project.. btw do you have any additional libraries?

Comment: Ahm, that happend AFTER a clean and rebuild....appcompat4, appcompat7 and sqliteassethelper are my libraries.

Comment: Please Write that down as an answer I will upvote....saved my day, thank you so much.....

Comment: lol oh ok..+1 for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clean rebuild and restart project.. btw do you have any additional libraries??
if so get rid of them
lol..